# Data sent through Data API from mobile not received in android wear?

Tags: android, wear-os, android-wear-data-api

Data sent through Data API from mobile app is not received in ondatachange of listenerservice in wearable  emulator.I can send a notification though, which indicates both are connected.Below my code,

DataAPI call (mobile)

```
   PutDataMapRequest putDataMapRequest = PutDataMapRequest.create(SharedConstants.START_FREE_RUN);
   putDataMapRequest.getDataMap().putString(SharedConstants.PROGRAM_TYPE,totalCountUpTimer);

    PutDataRequest request = putDataMapRequest.asPutDataRequest();
    Wearable.DataApi.putDataItem(mGoogleApiClient, request)
            .setResultCallback(new ResultCallback<DataApi.DataItemResult>() {
                @Override
                public void onResult(DataApi.DataItemResult dataItemResult) {
                    if (!dataItemResult.getStatus().isSuccess()) {
                        Log.e(TAG, "buildWatchOnlyNotification(): Failed to set the data, "
                                + "status: " + dataItemResult.getStatus().getStatusCode());
                    } else {
                        Log.d(TAG,"SuccessFully sent notification");
                    }
                }
            });
```

After which I am getting "successfully sent" log message.

Below is ListenerService in wear,

```
  public class ListenerService extends WearableListenerService {

  private static final String TAG =   ListenerService.class.getSimpleName();
  @Override
  public void onDataChanged(DataEventBuffer dataEvents) {
     super.onDataChanged(dataEvents);
     Log.d(TAG, "dchanged" + dataEvents);

  }
  @Override
  public void onMessageReceived(MessageEvent messageEvent) {
     Log.v(TAG, "onMessageReceivedWear: " + messageEvent);

     if  (SharedConstants.START_FREE_RUN.equals(messageEvent.getPath())) {
        // Request for this device open the attraction detail screen
        // to a specific tourist attraction
        String Distance = new String(messageEvent.getData());
        Log.d("ListenerService",Distance);

     }
 }
 }
```

and my service declaration in Android manifest,

```
    <service android:name=".services.ListenerService">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="com.google.android.gms.wearable.DATA_CHANGED" />
            <action android:name="com.google.android.gms.wearable.MESSAGE_RECEIVED" />
            <data android:scheme="wear" android:host="*" android:pathPrefix="*" />
       </intent-filter>
    </service>
  <meta-data
        android:name="com.google.android.gms.version"
        android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version" />
```

Did not add any permissions in wearable module.Do suggest.

Answer (score 1):

Use `android:pathPattern=".*"` instead of `android:pathPrefix="*"`